# Editable document in LaTeX

Tags: conversion, thesis, collaboration

I'm writing Engineer Thesis in LaTeX and my leading professor asked me to give him editable document with my thesis. Can I create editable document from `.tex` file? Or maybe there is a simple way to convert it to `.doc` or `.docx`? Please Help. I'm creating in TexStudio.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Pandoc http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html

Comment: So he explicitly refuses to use the document's source? What about annotating a PDF? You have very nice annotation possibilities (like in SKIM for mac).

Comment: @Dror or more general the Adobe Reader on any OS (but on a Mac i prefer Skim).

Comment: Ask him, if editable would also mean LaTeX. Since your professor is probably an engineer himself he should be aware of it.

Comment: @Dror I haven't asked him if he wants source document. I thought I would look better if I give him f.e. .doc file.
When he did some corrections he used annotations in PDF but now he told me to prepare final version in editable file. I really don't know for what purpose.

Comment: @bohunn Give him `your-thesis.tex` source code and convince him `LaTeX way is the best` and conversion from `.tex` to `.doc` or even `.docx` is very cumbersome as it another Ph.D when you have many math,graphics etc.. Many people have switched to `LaTeX` lately for eg :[Do you use TeX for writing your thesis or only for its composition?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100024/15717). **Final Moral:** Either you change to `word` or Make your prof change to `LaTeX`, both should be in Sync.